# mootools inline Ajax call not working

Tags: ajax, onclick, mootools

I am trying to use mootools ajax requests to record clicks on outgoing links. So far here is what I'm doing.

Each link looks like follows:

```
<div id="1">    
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" onclick="clickRecord(1)">StackOverflow</a>
</div>
```

The javascript function clickRecord(id) is defined as follows:

```
function clickRecord(id){
    var u = "record.php";   
    var req = new Request({
      method: 'post',
      url: u,
      data:{'id':id},
      onComplete:function(response){
      }
    }).send();

}
```

The problem I have is this. If I add a return false; to the onclick="" declaration, everything works fine, of course the problem there is that click does not take the user to the intended page. If I do not have the return false; then it seems like the ajax call is never executed.

I thought the onclick event should execute first and then only the default action should execute. Is this not the case?

There is an even stranger scenario if you use onmousedown event instead. It seems like on Firefox, if you use the onmousedown event, once you go to the new page, you cant simply navigate back to the old page, you have to **refresh** the old page. Else the call is not executed. This does not happen on IE.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `onclick` - very 1995.

Instead attach an event to the element and use `event.stop()`, ie:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" data-id="1">StackOverflow</a>
```

JS:

```
document.getElements('a').addEvents({
    click: function(event) {
        event.stop();
        var u = 'record.php';
        var req = new Request({
            method: 'post',
            url: u,
            data: {
                'id': this.get('data-id');
            },
            onComplete: function(response) {}
        }).send();
    }
});
```

Btw. `<div id="1">` this is not valid in HTML, an ID'd needs to start with a letter.

Comment: Hi Oskar, thank you for the update. However I am quite eager to get it working via onclick event. The main reason is that I will not have the full control over which of the <a> links need to be tracked. It is not all the links, but a specific set of links that are assigned as banners. Of course this can be resolved by naming all the <a>s with a specific name. One other reason why I need it to be onclick is because most of the clients have seen the Google Analytics event tracking and have used it. They now want a similar method integrated to their sites. Please see below for a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Found an answer to one of the questions:

1. The inline mootools request did not execute when declared through the onclick().
   It seems this was caused by the script not being synchronous. So probably it returns without actually fully committing the request, and the browser then moves to another page breaking the execution. Adding a synchronous call to the script fixes the problem:

> ```
> function clickRecord(id){
>     var u = "record.php";   
>     var req = new Request({
>       async:false,
>       method: 'post',
>       url: u,
>       data:{'id':id},
>       onComplete:function(response){
>       }
>     }).send();
> }
> ```

The second problem that was mentioned on the onmousedownevent, i.e. firefox not executing the ajax call if the browser navigates back is still unsolved. However I am leaving that to be as that wasn't the main question raised.